# Flutter ( Flip Page View ) : How to create Mid Flip Page View using flip_board package?

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

I want to create Mid Flip Page View.I am using "flip_board" package to create but don't know how to manage it.

[image: I want something like this in a pageview format]

Answer (score 0):

After hours of sacrifice, I found this app code which has **"Mid Flip Page View"**

Simply extract "**FlipPanel**" widget and add it to your project and apply like below :

```
FlipPanel<Blog>(
    itemStream: Stream.fromIterable([------List-------]),
    height: size(context).height,
    itemBuilder: <Blog>(context, blog, p2, p3) {
      return Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        child : Text("data")
      );
    });
```

Reference: https://github.com/jmolins/flutboard